# shopify- combine header logo and navbar

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, shopify

so shopify is driving me insane and I am struggling to locate which fricking file to even edit to change the code. right now I have a header and a nav bar. I want the navbar to be the header and the logo to display in the middle of the navbar. (identical to www.greatlakescollection.com) please someone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using the initial theme installed on the online store of your shopify. To customize the html/css of the page you can follow the guidilines in : https://help.shopify.com/themes/customization#edit-html-css

The Edit HTML/CSS page lets you change the .liquid files that make up your theme.

> From your Shopify admin, click Online Store, and then click Themes (or press G W T).
>   Click the ... menu, then click Edit HTML/CSS.
>   Open the theme.liquid file in the layout.

Find the divs with class "site-header__logo" and change the class large--left to large--center.